# MSAccess (2007) - popup and modal form - instancing via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got stuck in a very annoying matter.

I need to open a form within a class module, passing the class itself to the form so that the form can use all of the class properties and methods.
I am talking about a form, NOT ABOUT A USERFORM. (The problem would not exist in this second case).
The form must be both popup and modal.

So let's suppose this code in the calling-class method that opens the form:

```
sub OpenFormMethodOfTheCallingClass
    set MyForm = new [Form_FormToBeOpened]
    with MyForm
        set .MyFatherClass = Me
        .SetFocus ' ... this opens the form
        MsgBox "Ok, user has closed the form ..."
    end with
end sub
```

This way, the code flow DOESN'T "STOP" INSIDE THE FORM.
I mean that the message "Ok, user has closed the form ..." appears immediately, "in front" of the opened form.
And then, obviously, the method ends and the form (again, obviously) disappears, as it's an instance of the closing method.

In design view, both Popup and Modal form are set to TRUE.

Setting the two properties in the calling procedure this way:

```
with MyForm
    .Modal = True
    .PopUp = True
    (...)
```

... doesn't help at all, as:
- MODAL doesn't affect the code flow behavior
- POPUP can't be set (!): it returns a run-time error.

The only way I've found to achieve my goal is opening this way:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormToBeOpened", WindowMode:=acDialog
```

This way, the code flow "stucks" into the form, and only when user closes the form itself the flow returns to the calling procedure, and its following instruction.
But the problem is that I can't pass the calling class to the form.
OK, someone could object that: as my form is MODAL, no multiple contemporaneous instances of the form can be opened by the user, and therefore I could pass any property of the calling class to the form in some other ways ("bridge-public-variables", or a JSON in OpenArgs ...). But it's ... really horrible.

I fear, don't know why, this is is a very stupid question, with a simple answer. :)

Let's see.

Thks,

FL

Answer (score 1):

That's by design. Access runs a single thread, so dialog means dialog.

You can pass static values with OpenArgs to the dialog form, but you can also let this - when opened - pull data and properties from the calling form.

That code doesn't have to be ugly.

It may be that WinForms of .Net and Visual Studio will better fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant dialog. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you Gustav: I totally agree with you about you "philosophical" remarks (I mean about Access that's not the correct environment for structured coding).

However, my problem was that I didn't need to "pull data and properties from the calling FORM", but rather from a calling CLASS.

If you read again my question (don't do it!, :D the philosophical suggestion wins), you'll see that I can't prepare the CALLED form as an object passing the calling class in a correct "clean" way, but I can only open it with DoCmd, that prevents me to interact with it from the calling class.

Comment: Then, I guess, your only option left is to save (a copy of) the form where  Modal and PopUp are set to True.

Comment: Not even that (!). According to the experiments I made (and if I well remember them), instancing a form (I repeat it: a form, not a user form) in the "correct" (?) way, I mean creating an object, setting its properties and then showing it, makes the "modal feature" not working in any case.

My only option is making the form appearing with DoCmd.OpenForm "FormToBeOpened", WindowMode:=acDialog ... but it prevents me from "pre-setting" form user object properties.

Therefore: "object-bridge-global-variable" ... no other possibilities, it seems. (Ugly.)

Answer (score 0):

Create form class Form_Popup with .Modal and .Popup = True.

In Form_Popup's module

- Add property variable, propFils_Class of type Fils_Class (or Variant, if not allowed)
- Add `Public Sub Let Fils_Class (inputFils_Class as Variant)` and `Public Sub Get Fils_Class (inputFils_Class as Variant)` procedures to set and retrieve the propFils_Class

  - I'm assuming you need the input variables to be variants, but you may be able to pass them as Fils_Class type, not sure.
- In the code requiring Form_Popup:

  ```
  Dim frm as Form, varFils_Class as Fils_Class

  '<set up varFils_Class here>

  Set frm = New Form_Popup 
  'or Docmd.OpenForm "Popup" hidden etc., then you need to directly reference the form, e.g. Set frm = Forms("Popup")

  frm.Fils_Class = varFils_Class

  frm.Visible = True

  Do While frm.Visible
    Sleep 1
    DoEvents
    '<at some point actions on Form_Popup set .Visible to False>
  Loop

  varFilsClass = frm.FilsClass

  '<do other actions with frm as needed>
  set frm = Nothing
  ```

Comment: You're right usncahill. In my question, I forgot saying that I actually use the "do-loop approach" from time to time to solve this matter, but I really don't like it because of the wasting of resources that it involves.